# Hide search input field and search results when user clicks outside of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to hide both the input field and the search results box when user clicks outside of them?

Currently if you hover your mouse over `#search-btn` both `#search-container` and `#search-results` will appear. If you click anywhere except on `#search-container` both will disappear.

I want so that I can click on `#search-results` without both of them disappearing.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emils/d2sn7q6L/

HTML:

```
<div id="search-container">
  <form id="search-form">
    <input id="search" type="search">
  </form>
</div> <!-- End search-box -->

<a id="search-btn" class="search-icon" href="#">search</a>

<div id="search-results"></div> <!-- End search-results -->
```

JS:

```
var searchInput = $("#search-container");
var searchResults = $("#search-results");

var showSearchInput = function() {
  searchInput.show();
  searchResults.show();
  if(searchInput.is(":visible")) {
    $("#search").focus();
  }
};
$("#search-btn").hover(showSearchInput);

searchInput.focusout(function(e) {
  searchInput.hide();
  searchResults.hide();
});
```

Comment: do you really need to click outside to hide ?. you can just use another button to hide them.

Comment: I am converting a .psd to html/css. There is no close button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about replacing and using $(document) and .is("hover") and check if any of the elements are hovered when the elements have the mouse on, we can guess that if the document has been clicked and in that moment any of the elements have the mouse on then any of the element were actually clicked, so it will look like this:

```
$(document).click(function(){ //if the document has been clicked
if( !($("#search-container").is(":hover"))&&
    !($("#search-results").is(":hover"))&&
    !($("#search-btn").is(":hover"))
   )//if any of these elements have the mouse then me know the user didn't click on them
{searchInput.hide();searchResults.hide();}}//hide the boxes
```

i hope this helps you, [here are the changes](https://jsfiddle.net/d2sn7q6L/42/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried hiding not on focusout, but on document click and then excluding clicks on the form or search results.

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
  if ($(evt.target).closest('#search-container, #search-results').length == 0) {
    searchInput.hide();
    searchResults.hide();
  }
});
```

See modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4ne5r2w/

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your *searchInput.focusout* function with:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).attr('id') != "search-results") {
        searchInput.hide();
        searchResults.hide();
    }
});
```

This way you're only performing the action when a user clicks on anything except for the *searchResults* element.

Comment: great answer. i was searching the net on how to click a div. but i forgot it could be done by using DOCUMENT..nice work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It just hides both if I click anywhere.

Comment: Hi @Rudolph, apologies, I've just amended my example as it was double-negative (if not not equals to) instead of (if not equals to). Should work now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Hide search result when clicked outside search field
let searchInput = $(".search-container");
let searchResults = $(".search-result");
    
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest(".search-container, .search-result").length == 0) {
    searchInput.show();
    searchResults.hide();
  } else {
    searchResults.show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like an idea to hide search field ;) it may be needed by your project and in example above using `.on("focusout", function ...` does the job. As optimisation I would suggest wrapping them in a kind of container not to call show() and hide() twice per iteration at least...